# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'rakash@tech.com'

Tags: django

This is the line in which i am getting error:

```
  User.objects.filter(id__in=Setupuser.share_KB_with.through.objects.
  values_list("user_id").filter(setupuser_id=Setupuser.objects.
  values_list("email_id",flat=True).filter(email_id="rakash@tech.com") 
  [0]))
```

There are two tables "User" and "Setupuser".I want to retrieve some objects from User by applying filters on setupuser.
How can i resolve error

**models**

```
 class User(AbstractUser):
   username=models.CharField(max_length=20,default="")
   email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
   phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$',
                                 message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'.Min 9 to Max 15 digits allowed.")
phone_number = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=17)


class Setupuser(models.Model):
   your_nickname=models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=False,null=True)
   your_organization=models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=False,null=True)
   your_phone_no=models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=False,null=True)
   email_id=models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=False,unique=True)
   share_KB_with = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

Comment: Well you here use an `email_id` which is an integer, but `'rakash...` is not an integer, nor an string that contains an integer.

Comment: Perhaps it is better if you post the models for `User`, `Email`, etc.

Comment: added models....,In advance thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown the full traceback of the error, but it looks like `email_id` was a `ForeignKey` or `IntegerField` at some point. After changing it to a `CharField`, you need to run `manage.py makemigrations` and then `manage.py migrate` to change the column type in the database.

Answer (score 0):

issue resolved small mistake in query. Instead of "id" given "email_id". id is integer field and email_id is char field.

**Before:**

```
 User.objects.filter(id__in=Setupuser.share_KB_with.through.objects.
 values_list("user_id").filter(setupuser_id=Setupuser.objects.
 values_list("email_id",flat=True).filter(email_id="rakash@tech.com") 
 [0]))
```

**after**

```
 User.objects.filter(id__in=Setupuser.share_KB_with.through.objects.
 values_list("user_id").filter(setupuser_id=Setupuser.objects.
 values_list("id",flat=True).filter(email_id="rakash@tech.com") 
 [0]))
```